# Cannot purchase a domain from Hostinger after canceling it in Wix

Tags: domain

I had a domain in Wix, but Hostinger offered us a better deal with a free domain. So, after our plan at Wix ended I purchased a new one with Hostinger, but it seems that Wix is still holding the domain name; hence, I cannot purchase it in Hostinger.

I tried waiting, but it has been more than 3 months already. I still didn't talk to Wix because I am afraid they might deliberately keep it even longer, so I would purchase it from them instead.

What can be done about it? Is there a way to somehow completely remove this domain from Wix?

Important note- I currently do not own the domain. I am trying to purchase it from Hostinger instead of Wix (but Wix still holds on to it).

Comment: Perhaps check if you need to execute the steps xplained here: https://www.websitebuilderexpert.com/web-hosting/how-to-transfer-domain-name/

Comment: **I still didn't talk to Wix because I am afraid they might deliberately keep it even longer, so I would purchase it from them instead. What can be done about it? Is there a way to somehow completely remove this domain from Wix?** - Contact Wix support. They can't keep it if you legally own it. - https://support.wix.com/en/article/transferring-your-wix-domain-away-from-wix-2477749

Comment: Did you have hosting or domain registration at Wix or both? And which service was actually expired?